# Rails App works locally but crashes when deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to open my rails application through heroku after its been deployed to heroku but keep getting an application error and cant figure it out. This is my full error message:

```
2020-03-28T05:36:08.883484+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2020-03-28T05:36:08.883487+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:36:08.883490+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-28T05:36:08.883493+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2020-03-28T05:36:08.883514+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-28T05:36:08.883514+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:36:08.883515+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
2020-03-28T05:36:08.883515+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
2020-03-28T05:36:08.883518+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:36:08.883527+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2020-03-28T05:36:09.000809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-28T05:36:08.983756+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-03-28T05:45:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user gavinsmyth1998@gmail.com
2020-03-28T05:47:05.219450+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 371fbb06 by user gavinsmyth1998@gmail.com
2020-03-28T05:47:05.219450+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user gavinsmyth1998@gmail.com
2020-03-28T05:47:06.240929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-03-28T05:47:11.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-03-28T05:47:12.913174+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 53780 -e production`
2020-03-28T05:47:18.871183+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from <main> at /app/config/application.rb:7)
2020-03-28T05:47:18.900508+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2020-03-28T05:47:18.900510+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 6.0.2.2 application starting in production
2020-03-28T05:47:18.900511+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753020+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753201+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/unit_converter/lib/unit_converter.rb:2:in `<main>': UnitConverter is not a module (TypeError)
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753225+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753226+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753228+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753246+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753248+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753264+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:16:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753265+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:381:in `const_get'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753282+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:381:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753283+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:723:in `block in ls'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753299+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:720:in `foreach'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753299+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:720:in `ls'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753315+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:376:in `block in eager_load'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753315+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:368:in `synchronize'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753317+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:368:in `eager_load'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753333+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:483:in `each'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753334+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:483:in `eager_load_all'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753336+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:122:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753352+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753352+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753354+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753375+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753378+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753381+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753382+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753385+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753387+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753406+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753406+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753408+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753424+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753424+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753440+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753440+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753457+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753459+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753476+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753476+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753493+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753495+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753511+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753513+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753529+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:49:in `require_relative'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753530+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753550+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753550+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753553+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753556+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753577+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753577+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753579+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753598+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753600+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753616+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753618+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:39:in `start'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753634+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753635+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753651+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753651+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753667+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753668+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753684+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753685+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753701+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753702+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753722+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753722+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753725+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753728+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753748+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753748+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753750+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.753767+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2020-03-28T05:47:20.930773+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-28T05:47:20.934097+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-03-28T05:47:20.911352+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-03-28T05:47:28.215815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 11530 -e production`
2020-03-28T05:47:34.875311+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from <main> at /app/config/application.rb:7)
2020-03-28T05:47:34.899134+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2020-03-28T05:47:34.899138+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 6.0.2.2 application starting in production
2020-03-28T05:47:34.899139+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
2020-03-28T05:47:36.057620+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-28T05:47:35.944829+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2020-03-28T05:47:35.944955+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/unit_converter/lib/unit_converter.rb:2:in `<main>': UnitConverter is not a module (TypeError)
2020-03-28T05:47:35.944979+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.944980+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.944980+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.944981+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.944993+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.944994+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:16:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.944997+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:381:in `const_get'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.944997+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:381:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.944997+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:723:in `block in ls'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.944998+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:720:in `foreach'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.944998+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:720:in `ls'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945001+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:376:in `block in eager_load'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945003+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:368:in `synchronize'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945005+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:368:in `eager_load'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945007+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:483:in `each'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945010+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:483:in `eager_load_all'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945035+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:122:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945036+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945036+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945036+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945037+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945040+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945040+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945043+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945046+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945049+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945051+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945054+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945056+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945058+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945080+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945082+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945082+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945083+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945086+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945087+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945087+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945089+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945092+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945094+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945096+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945100+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:49:in `require_relative'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945102+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945104+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945127+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945128+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945128+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945129+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945132+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945132+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945135+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945137+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945139+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945141+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:39:in `start'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945163+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945164+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945164+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945164+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945167+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945168+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945171+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945171+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945174+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945176+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945197+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945198+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945198+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945198+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945201+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945201+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945203+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
2020-03-28T05:47:35.945207+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2020-03-28T05:47:36.041261+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

I've pushed it up to github and done this command to link it with heroku:

```
git push heroku master
```

I've also done

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I've been trying to figure it out for a while now but no luck. I know it probably has something to do with this but don't know why:

```
/app/app/unit_converter/lib/unit_converter.rb:2:in `<main>': UnitConverter is not a module (TypeError)
```

These are the only two places that I can see UnitConverter being used. The gem I created:

```
require 'singleton'
module UnitConverter

    class ConversionError < StandardError
    end
    class Weight
      include Singleton
    # lookup table
    CONVERSIONS = {
      kg: {
        pounds: 2.20462,
        stone: 0.157473,
      },
      pounds: { 
        kg: 0.453592,
        stone: 0.0714286
      },
      stone: {
        kg: 6.35029,
        pounds: 14  
      }
    }
    weight = Weight.instance

    def convert(value, from, to:)
      raise ConversionError, "Value is not numeric" unless value.is_a? Numeric
      raise ConversionError, "Value #{value} is not positive" unless value >= 0
      "#{value * conversion_ratio(from, to) }#{to.to_s}"
    end

    def conversions(value, unit)
        CONVERSIONS[unit].keys.map do |other_unit|
          convert(value, unit, to: other_unit)
        end
      end

    private
    def conversion_ratio(from, to)
      begin
        CONVERSIONS.fetch(from).fetch(to)
      rescue KeyError
        raise ConversionError, "Cannot convert #{from.to_s} to #{to.to_s}"
      end
    end
  end
  end
```

and when Im calling it in another class:

```
 def converter
    @input1 = params[:value]
    @input2 = params[:unit]
    @result = ::UnitConverter::Weight.instance.conversions(@input1.to_i, @input2.to_sym)
    @measurements = Measurement.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
    cookies[:email] = current_user.email
    @email = cookies[:email]
    render :index
    end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try you know actually like reading the stack trace? `app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:17:in `on_file_autoloaded': expected file /app/app/unit_converter/lib/unit_converter.rb to define constant Lib::UnitConverter, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError).`

Comment: I did see that but and I changed it to that cause when I had it as UnitConverter it was giving me an error saying UnitConverter is not a module

Comment: ill edit my question for the original error

Comment: Feels to me like you use the name `UnitConverter` for both a class and a module at the same time. Search your app for `module UnitConverter` and `class UnitConverter`.

Comment: the error is in `2020-03-28T05:47:35.944955+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/unit_converter/lib/unit_converter.rb:2:in `<main>': UnitConverter is not a module (TypeError)` this line. Check it and add more info if you can't fix.

Comment: I've searched everywhere to see if I created a UnitConverter Class but cant see it could it be something else?

Comment: is it cause I use require'unit_converter' in my controller when I dont need to